# Cloudbees play plugin set run-time parameters

Tags: playframework-2.1, cloudbees

I am trying to set a runtime parameter java_version for my Play 2 app. How could I set runtime parameter using sbt-cloudbees-play-plugin?

Cloudbees SDK

```
$ play dist
$ bees app:deploy -a a -t play2 -R java_version=1.7 dist/myapp.zip
```

Build.scala

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
.settings(cloudBeesSettings :_*)
.settings(
        CloudBees.applicationId := Some(""),
        CloudBees.deployParams := Map("runtime.java_version" -> "1.7")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess sbt-cloudbees-play-plugin just don't let you pass such option
But as you've set runtime parameter once you don't need to set on all deployments, it's tied to application ID.